# Seaglass theme for Java not painting

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, seaglass

I have implemented a Seaglass jar theme for my appication, but the theme doesn't work.  I have tried add it into different points in my code but nothing I have tried works.  Someone please help me.

```
private void initialize() {


        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 577, 443);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel, null);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel_1, null);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", null, panel_2, null);

        .. rest of components.
```

I have already added the JAR as reference in my project, added it to the build path.

Comment: Personally, I like the **Nimbus** Look&Feel better than SeaGlass.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should have your L&F code as the first item of business within the application's starting **main()** method. This should be in place before you start applying components to your application. You also need to add the **[seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.1.jar](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22com.seaglasslookandfeel%22+AND+a%3A%22seaglasslookandfeel%22&search_type=av&a=seaglasslookandfeel)** file (*for JRE 1.8 and later*) into the Class-path for your project.

> **In Eclipse:**

1. Put the **seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.1.jar** file in a designated
   folder in your project;
2. Right Click your project folder in Eclipse then go to **Build Path**
   then select **Configure Build Path**;
3. Under **Libraries** tab, click **Add External Jar** and go to the
   folder that contains the jar file;
4. Click the **OK** button then in your code, go to your `public static
   void main(String[] args)` method and copy paste this code at the very beginning of it:

   ```
   try {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
   } 
   catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
          InstantiationException | 
          IllegalAccessException | 
          javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { 
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
   }
   ```

> **In NetBeans (8.0+):**

1. Put the **seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.1.jar** file in a designated
   folder in your project;
2. Right Click your project folder in the NetBean's **Projects** pane then select the **Properties** menu item (at bottom of menu);
3. In the **Project Properties** dialog window now displayed select
   **Libraries** from the **Categories** pane;
4. Now select the **Compile** tab then select the **Add JAR/Folder**
   button and go to the folder that contains the jar file and select it then select the **OK** button;
5. The **seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.1.jar** JAR file should now be displayed within the **Compile-time Libraries** pane. Click the **OK** button within the **Project Properties** dialog;
6. In your code, go to your `public static void main(String[] args)`
   method and copy paste this code at the very beginning of it:

   ```
   try {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
   } 
   catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
          InstantiationException | 
          IllegalAccessException | 
          javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { 
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
   }
   ```

Your **main()** method should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
           InstantiationException | 
           IllegalAccessException | 
           javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    // The rest of your main() method code here....
}
```

The SeaGlass Look&Feel should work now.

Comment: thks a lot, where can i download nimbus?

Comment: @Volazh Nimbus is built in

Comment: @MadProgrammer got it, but still to old theme, do you know a plain-white modern theme for java for free?

Comment: @Volazh Nope - personally, I just use the system look and feel. Nimbus is based on synthetica look and feel, which is highly customisable